# How to change the frame title from `emacs@host` to visited file name

Tags: frames, gtk3

I am using Emacs 24.5.1 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, with Gnome 3.16, and the title of the GTK window with Emacs in it is always `emacs@hostname`. How can I change it to the name of the current file I'm editing?

Comment: Why do you need this? I'm curious for your use case.  The file name is already shown in the mode line, isn't it?

Comment: Gnome in Overview mode has the window title in big text below the window thumbnail, the one in the mode line is too small to see.

Comment: Just a side remark: If you have several frames open - for example if you open a file in another frame with `C-x 5 f` - then each frame will show the buffer name as title. It's only when you have just a single frame that you see "emacs@hostname".

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm The title bar can show the buffer name and mode of the minibuffer, which the mode line doesn't display.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The file name as frame name

```lisp
    (setq-default frame-title-format '("%f"))
```

The file name and the major mode as frame name (my conf)

```lisp
    (setq-default frame-title-format '("%f [" mode-name "]"))
```

See

- [Variables Used in the Mode Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html)
- [`%`-Constructs in the Mode Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/_0025_002dConstructs.html)

Comment: Use `%b` to get the filename without the path

Comment: '%b' is also better for unsaved buffers, like "*scratch*"

Comment: Does somebody know how to set it in `custom-set-variables`?

Comment: @yPhil ```(custom-set-variables
 '(setq-default frame-title-format '("%f [%m]")))```  ?

Comment: `%m` is now deprecated in favor of the variable `mode-name`. See [%-Constructs in the Mode Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/_0025_002dConstructs.html)

Answer (score 9):

Make emacs' window title show path of the current file:

```lisp
(setq-default frame-title-format
              '(:eval
                (format "%s@%s: %s %s"
                        (or (file-remote-p default-directory 'user)
                            user-real-login-name)
                        (or (file-remote-p default-directory 'host)
                            system-name)
                        (buffer-name)
                        (cond
                         (buffer-file-truename
                          (concat "(" buffer-file-truename ")"))
                         (dired-directory
                          (concat "{" dired-directory "}"))
                         (t
                          "[no file]")))))
```