# setq-default not taking effect for emacs

Tags: frame-title-format

I am having trouble getting emacs title to show full path, I followed below thread and copied the setq-default cmd into my ~/.emacs, but it still shows emacs@host in the title. I am using emacs 24.3.1 on GNU/Linux

```el
(setq-default frame-title-format '("%f [%m]"))
```

[How to change the frame title from `emacs@host` to visited file name](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16834/how-to-change-the-frame-title-from-emacshost-to-visited-file-name)

Comment: Did you restart emacs after you changed the `.emacs` file?

Comment: Yes, I opened new emacs windows.

Comment: Depending on what exactly you did, that may not be enough. Did you kill the emacs that you were running before you changed the file? And then started a brand-spanking-new instance of emacs that did not have *any* relation to the previous one?

Comment: yes I opened a brand new emacs window, even on a new terminal window